# Y axis in the graph partially displaying in dygraphs.

Tags: dygraphs

I have used `Dygraph` plugin. But its cutting on the y axis. It should display the complete graph by adjusting the y axis range. I don't expect my user to scroll it to see the complete graph. Please see the below attached image for ref.

[Cutting dygraphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFU8S.png)

```
chart = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("chart_div"), data,
{
      drawPoints: true,
      rollPeriod: 1,
      showRoller: true,
      animatedZooms: true,
      ylabel: 'CPU',
      xlabel: 'Processor Date Time',
      labels: label_val,
      interactionModel : {
          'mousedown' : downV3,
          'mousemove' : moveV3,
          'mouseup' : upV3,
          'click' : clickV3,
          'dblclick' : dblClickV3,
          'mousewheel' : scrollV3
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you share a live demo? This looks more likely to be a CSS issue than a dygraphs issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by adding valueRange: [0,80]. It was restricting the y-axis to show till 10 value only. I changed the roll period too, but failed to display the complete graph. So applied min and max point of y-axis. Let me know if there are any better ways.